# What imports do I need to make a jQuery popup dialog work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am very confused :)

I have these 2 jQuery imports:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.16/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js" />
```

and I think the bottom one is giving me errors on this page: http://www.problemio.com

The error is 404 not found.  What should be the import so I can get the out of the box library to work that will enable me to create popup dialog boxes for the user?

Thanks!

Comment: You *think* it's the second one? Pretty easy to find out, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two:

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.16/jquery-ui.min.js

Answer (score 1):

It's the first one that's not found. Use this URL instead (for the latest version of jQuery):

https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js

For more options, see the [Google Libraries API](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/devguide.html#jquery). The first script is the jQuery library itself. The second is jQuery UI. Both are required to create "popup dialog boxes" (I'm assuming you're talking about [jQuery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/)), and that should be it.

Answer (score 1):

Easy.  That top `src` should just be:

```
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js
```

The jQuery and jQuery-ui versions do not run concurrently.